# Inverse of the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. A simple consequence of the dominated convergence theorem is that

> If $f_n\to f$ a.e, and there exists a function $g\in L^p$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e. for all $n$, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

It is also well known that if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ then up to a subsequence, $f_n\to f$ a.e. This may be considered as a partial inverse of the above theorem.

My question is if the dominated convergence theorem is fully invertible. That is, does the following hold (and if so, why?):

> We have $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ if and only if any subsequence of $\left\{f_n\right\}$ (which I will not relabel) has a subsequence $\left\{f_{n_k}\right\}$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. and there exists a function $g\in L^p$ such that $|f_{n_k}|\leq g$ a.e. for all $k$.

More specifically, the missing part is showing that if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ then up to a subsequence there exists a dominating function.

I found a counterexample when we do not allow taking a subsequence, namely $$f_n(x)=n\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}]}(x),\qquad x\in (0,1)$$
Here $f_n\to 0$ in $L^1$ and a.e., but if $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e., necessarily $g\notin L^1$. However, if we allow taking subsequences, this is no longer a counterexample.

Comment: By "up to a subsequences" do you mean "for all subsequences, there is a sub-subsequence such that..."?

Comment: No, I mean that 'there is a subsequence such that [...]'

Comment: Then the "$\Leftarrow$" in your "if and only if" is not true: namely, consider a sequence $f_n=0$ if $n$ is odd and $f_n=\chi_{[0,1]}$ if $n$ is even, and $f=0$. It is dominated, there is a subsequence that converges in $L^p$ to $f$, but the sequence itself doesn't. On the other hand, "*A sequence* $f_n$ *converges to* $f$ *in* $L^p$ *if and only if for any subsequence* $f_{n_k}$ *there is a sub-subsequence* $f_{n_{k_h}}$ *such that* $f_{n_{k_h}}\to f$ *a.e. and* $f_{n_{k_h}}$ *is dominated by some* $g\in L^p$" is in fact true.

Comment: This was not intended, the $\Leftarrow$ should be read without the 'up to a subsequence' (in which case it is obviously true). But as I put it, your objection is definitely correct. I will correct the statement according to your comment, thanks!

Comment: Vitali's Convergence Theorem characterizes convergence in $L^{p}$ if $p \in [1,\infty)$.  (In particular, it generalizes the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem).  The text by Royden has a nice exposition.  Also see the Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are allowed to take subsequences, then you can indeed find a dominating function.

First, we make the assumption $f=0$.
Then we consider a subsequence of $f_n$ such that
$$
 \| f_{n_k} \|_{L^p} \leq 2^{-k}.
$$

Then you can define
$$
 g := \sum_{k=1}^\infty | f_{n_k} |
$$
and it can be seen that $g\in L^p$ and $g$ is a dominating function of $f_{n_k}$ for all $k$.

If $f\neq 0$, you can (with the method above) find a dominating function $g$ of $ f_{n_k}-f$ by the methods above.
Then, $g':= |f|+g$ is a dominating function for all $f_{n_k}$.

Comment: Very neat and simple solution. I wonder why this result is never stated in undergraduate analysis courses, it is nice (and also useful) to see that the dominated convergence theorem can be reversed.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa: But typically, the proof that each convergent sequence contains a pointwise a.e. convergent subsequence already contains this argument.